# How does right-clicking text and selecting a service work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, nspasteboard

[1] When I select and right-click any text in any app, I get a `Services` menu where I can click to invoke any service like `Search With Google`.

After clicking, a `NSPasteboard` object is automatically sent to the service containing the selected text.

[2] 3rd party apps can use the `BOOL NSPerformService ( NSString *itemName, NSPasteboard *pboard )` function to programatically invoke any service.

Here the app has to set the `NSPasteboard` object, which is sent to the service.

---

Is there a way to programatically invoke any service, but without setting the `NSPasteboard` object (the `NSPasteboard` object should automatically contain the selected text like in [1]) ?

How is the `NSPasteboard` object containing selected text sent to the service by OS X in [1]? Is there some private API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented in the [Services Implementation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html), in particular the [Using Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/using.html) chapter.

First, when the user opens the Services menu, Cocoa calls `-validRequestorForSendType:returnType:` on the objects in the responder chain to determine which combinations of send type and return type can be handled by which object, if any, based on its current state (e.g. the current selection). That controls which Services menu items are enabled.

When the user selects a service menu item, Cocoa creates a pasteboard and calls `-writeSelectionToPasteboard:types:` on the requestor object returned by `-validRequestorForSendType:returnType:`. That object should put the selection data on the provided pasteboard in whichever of the types it supports.

Cocoa then passes the pasteboard off to the system. The system communicates with Cocoa in the service provider process. Cocoa invokes `-<messageName>:userData:error:` on the service provider object in that process, where `<messageName>` comes from the description of the service in that app's Info.plist file. The service provider object is whatever the app registered with Cocoa using `NSRegisterServicesProvider()`.

The service provider processes the input data, if any, from the pasteboard and stores the return data, if any, to it.

After the provider is done, Cocoa in the original app calls `-readSelectionFromPasteboard:` on the requestor object. Again, the pasteboard is provided to that method.

Comment: Thanks. This is all good but instead of Cocoa, can my app do it? My app owns the service and should invoke it programatically. I can't simulate the hotkey of my app's service because it can be removed/changed by the user.

Comment: No, you can't programmatically initiate the invocation of a service on behalf of another app, at least not reliably. Under what circumstances would you want to? That is, if it's not being initiated by the user, what criteria would you use to initiate it?

Comment: It's initiated by the user, but not using hotkeys or such. Like custom hardware/SMS.

Comment: You might open a developer technical support incident with Apple to see if they have a suggestion. This sounds a bit like an accessibility issue. Have you tried using the Accessibility API to invoke an item from the Services menu rather than to copy the selection?

Comment: No but thanks that's a nice suggestion. Though if the user disables the service, it won't work. NSPerformService works without the service being enabled.